# E/sqlite3_android: [IKR-38846] ONEPLUS_NAME_PARTS_MATCH SQLITE_OK

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am getting this error when reading from SQLite database on OnePlus Nord AC2003. Everything works as intended, just wondering what I should do with the nasty-looking error in the stack trace.

D/ChatsDatabaseHelper: getAllChats: 1
E/sqlite3_android: [IKR-38846] ONEPLUS_NAME_PARTS_MATCH SQLITE_OK
D/ChatsDatabaseHelper: getAllChats: 2

and here is the code.

```
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Chats.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " +
            Chats.COLUMN_DATE + " DESC";
    Log.d(TAG, "getAllChats: 1");

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.d(TAG, "getAllChats: 2");
```

Comment: I see the same logs... Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: I'm still waiting for an answer myself... Although I do not think it is an actual problem, would be nice to know what it is.